# 2014 honda crv rear seat removal

Tags: honda, crv, seat

I need to remove rear seats from my 2014 Honda CRV. Looked online but was not able to find an answer on how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

When posting an answer please take into an account that I'm not a mechanic and rarely deal with any kind of tools, but I'm pretty sure I can remove a seat, if I'm given instructions. I just don't want to mess up anything during (dis)assembly, hence the reason for instructions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to actually remove the seats, or just fold them down?

Comment: @CharlieRB Need to actually remove the seats

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Installation is the Reverse of Removal. The seat cushion just lifts up.

---

Rear Seat-Back Removal and Installation

**Tonneau Cover (For Some Models)**

Remove the tonneau cover (A).

Fig 1: Removing Tonneau Cover

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Cargo Floor Cover**

Remove the cargo floor cover (A).

Fig 2: Removing Cargo Floor Cover

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Rear Damper Maintenance Cover**

Fold down the rear seat-back.

Pull up the rear damper maintenance cover (A) by hand to detach the hooks (B), then remove the rear damper maintenance cover.

Fig 3: Identifying Rear Damper Maintenance Cover And Hooks

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Rear Seat Foot Cover**

Pull up the rear seat foot cover (A) by hand to detach the clips (B).

Detach the hooks (C), then remove the rear seat foot cover.

**Left Side**

Fig 4: Identifying Rear Seat Foot Cover, Hooks And Clips (Left Side)

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Right Side**

Fig 5: Identifying Rear Seat Foot Cover, Hooks And Clips (Right Side)

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Rear Seat-Back**

Detach the rear seat-back arrange control cable (A) from the cable bracket (B).

Detach the cable clip (C), then disconnect the seat-back arrange control cable from the rear seat cushion foot (D).

Fig 6: Disconnecting Seat-Back Arrange Control Cable From Rear Seat Cushion Foot

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

Pull up the edge of seat-back cover (A), then detach the clips (B).

Left Side: Remove the mounting bolts (C), then remove the rear seat-back (D).

Right Side: Remove the mounting bolts (C) and the anchor bolt (E), then remove the rear seat-back (F).

**Left Side**

Fig 7: Pulling Edge Of Seat-Back Cover (Left Side)

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.

**Right Side**

Fig 8: Pulling Edge Of Seat-Back Cover (Right Side)

[image]
Courtesy of AMERICAN HONDA MOTOR CO., INC.